# GetProcessForPID error -600 with some process

Tags: macos-carbon

I am trying to access a process to send a key with CGEventPostToPSN later. But my problem is that I can not get the running process. I am using the following code:

```
     pid_t pid = GetPIDForProcessName("myprocess");
        NSLog(@"PID: %d", pid);

        ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, pid };
        OSStatus status = GetProcessForPID(pid, &psn);

        if (status != noErr) {
            NSLog(@"OSStatus KO PID: %d  %d %d", status, noErr, pid);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"OSStatus OK PID: %d  %d %d", status, noErr, pid);

    CGEventRef keyDown;
    keyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)0, TRUE);     
    CGEventRef keyUp;
    keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)0, FALSE);  
    CGEventPostToPSN(&psn, keyDown);
    CFRelease(keyDown);
    CGEventPostToPSN(&psn, keyUp);
    CFRelease(keyUp);
}
```

I am using the class "GetPID.h" to get the PID as an integer, and this seems to work correctly. But I get an error 600 "No eligible process with specified process serial number" in GetPIDForProcessName status.

I have tested some processes and this code works, but does not work with others. I have no very clear difference between processes can be

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every process has a process serial number, just the apps.  The docs for `GetProcessForPID` fail to say that, but see Technical Q&A QA1123.

Edit to add: Here's a quote from that document...

> Q: How do I get a list of all processes on Mac OS X?
>
> A: Well, that depends on how you define "process". If you want to list all of the running applications you should use the Carbon Process Manager routine GetNextProcess. This will return a list of all application processes, including those running in the Carbon, Cocoa, and Classic environments. However, this doesn't return a list of non-application (daemon) processes.

Comment: …If you have a copy of it. It's not available online anymore. (The URL for it *was*: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html )

Comment: @PeterHosey: I see, you're right.  If I search docs in Xcode 3.2.6, I find it in the 10.6 Core Library, but if I search docs in Xcode 4.2, it's not there.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. May be that my choice is not the right way then

Comment: Thanks @JWWalker.I've used in my code `OSStatus status = GetNextProcess(&psn);` and runs successfully. The second problem is CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent. Do you know if this is correct routine to send a keystroke to my process?

Comment: @JoelP., yes, once you have the psn, you would use `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` and `CGEventPostToPSN`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us examples of process names that do and don't work? The name of a process is arbitrary and might not match the human-readable name of the application. For instance, Time Machine runs in the background as "`backupd`".

If you tell us what it is you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to suggest an alternate way to accomplish it.

Comment: I edit my question with my full code, so you see what I'm trying to do, and if it is the right way. Otherwise my process name is right because GetPIDForProcessName return the right PID of my process. I try GetProcessForPID with for example "Address Book" process and not error.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: For example if i test this code with "TextEdit" process run right. But my process is a universal binary that needs some keystrokes to operate.

Comment: @JoelP.: What are the name and PID of the process you are unable to get the PSN of?

Comment: Again, you probably shouldn't be going by process name. What's the actual process you're trying to find?