# How to debug this MacOS old bug: The application "Preview.app" is not open anymore

Tags: macos, debugging, process, dtrace

Since many versions of MacOS, I got different applications leaving a ghost
version only visible at the Finder and Dock level but not at the basic
Unix level.
Here is the usual error message the Finder does display when trying to start
such a ghost application:
[image]

Meanwhile, `Activity Monitor` doesn't show any `Preview` process, and moreover
the Unix command `ps` either:

```
# ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|Preview)'
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
#
```

Next, the Dock does display a small dot near the application icon, but refuse
to force quit the ghost application.

### Tested and failing solutions

The usual receipe <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>from the Finder
doesn't permit to force quit the ghost application.

Many not tested ( by their authors ) receipes talk of removing preferences files, but since these
files are only open by the running application, this advice can only lead to a waste of time and a loss of working preferences.
Killing the Finder or the Dock is possible but doesn’t
fix the bad vision of the ghost application.

The MacOS cannot shutdown through the Finder menu entry:
` > Shut Down...` since the Finder cannot get rid of the ghost application
it sees as running when it isn't, here `Preview`.

On the other hand, a very basic Unix command permit to get a clean and fast
shutdown, since at the Unix level there isn't any application impossible
to kill:

```
/usr/bin/sudo shutdown -h now 'Finder see ghost applications'
```

### Spread of the problem

From my experience this problem is concerning Yosemite and High Sierra.
If you had the same problem on any more recent version of MacOS, could you
signal it within the comments.

Versions of MacOS exhibiting the problem:

- Yosemite
- El Capitan
- Sierra
- High Sierra
- Mojave
- Big Sur

Applications exhibiting the problem:

- Preview
- Safari
- TeamViewer
- XQuartz

From what I read in different discussion groups, it looks like any application
might reach this state of ghost for the Finder and the Dock.
It is a very large spectrum problem, and Apple doesn't look to have figured
it and doesn't provide any decent workaround or solution ( but the stupid and
huge waste of time: reinstall MacOS. Stupid because you can't give such
an advice when you don't understand a problem. )

### Simple workaround

The application seen as a ghost by the Finder is not the origin of the
problem and none of its preference files.
A simple demonstration can be obtained by starting it without the Finder:

In a `Terminal` simply enter for example:

```
$ open -n -a Preview.app
$
```

and you will get a fresh new `Preview` running with all its usual preferences and functions available. This new version will get a new icon within the `Dock`.

### Analysis of the problem

Since I didn't find any decent explanation of this problem and no clean fix
of it I started my own investigation with the help of the `truss` command which traces every key event within a Unix process running.

First I tried in a Terminal window:

```
$ /usr/bin/sudo dtruss -W Preview
```

and on another Terminal Window I tried to start Preview through:

```
$ open -a Preview.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Preview.app with error -600.
$
```

but nothing appeared within the `dtruss` track, meaning that Preview didn't even start and of course none of its preference files were opened.

Through a small program tracking all events, I was able to figure out that
the program responsible of the error window is `CoreServicesUIAgent`. But making different kind of `snoop` on this process I wasn't able to find
on which file or internal DB it was making this diagnosis.

`lsappinfo(8)` shows that `Preview` is registered among services, but the PID is one of a process not existing anymore:

```
% lsappinfo info -app Preview
[...]
    pid = 16898 !cgsConnection [...]
[...]
%
```

### How to furter invistigate this large spectrum bug

My state of understanding of the problem is that there is a false view of the
processes running on MacOS from the Finder and the Dock.

What may lead to this corrupted image of the processes on the system?

Which tools would be the best suited to further investigate this bug?

Where could I find any documentation about this `LSOpenURLsWithRole` and
the meaning of its error codes?

Comment: LSOpenURLsWithRole => LS = Launch Services framework, Roles https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/lsrolesmask

Comment: I think it's a dead end. It's failing on getting PID inside. You can use hopper app and look for (CMD+F) 0xfffffffffffffda8 (-600)  It's failing on LSApplicationCopyByASN(__LSSession const*, unsigned long long) which calls LSApplication::CopyProcess(__LSSession const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) which call one of these 2: LSSessionCopySystemProcessApplication(__LSSession const*)  LSApplication::CopyProcessByPid(__LSSession const*, int, bool) PS: Big Sur made reverse engineering harder. Use older frameworks from mojave/catalina

Comment: also try "ps -e" or "ps auxm"

Comment: @MarekH: I share your analysis: "It's failing on getting PID inside." How may I force `launchservicesd` ( if I guessed right which daemon is making this association ) to free this wrong association: app → PID, and make a fresh one?

Comment: All the `ps` war options were used: nothing. My chance is that I have a live case on `High Sierra` where Apple hasn't yet killed too many analysis tools.

Comment: I would look at Dock.app (if you can see the app there). On top there are more variables than pid. Namely psn and cid. psn = process serial number. Look for those as well I would be able to debug + reverse engineer but I cannot simulate this bug. "Mac OS X assigns a unique process serial number ("PSN") to all apps launched via GUI. It's used for identifying various processes and instances of executables." http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/prmref_main/data_type_5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000208/C001951

Comment: Look here is your error -600 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639379/getprocessforpid-error-600-with-some-process  To find your hanging process:   https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html

Comment: If you encounter you can look for processes using this https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/blob/master/filesystems-c/grabfs/GetPID.c just compile it and see if you can find something.